# How to dynamically define AppBarLayout height according to Material Ratio keylines

Tags: android, material-design, android-appbarlayout

Normally I define Height of **AppBarLayout** as fixed `dp` in `xml` layout. For example;

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height" />
```

When I learn more about **[Google material design](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing)** guideline, I gradually understand it has **absolute ratio** to define width and height (dimension) of **AppBarLayout** like in the following picture.

To follow these **aspect ratio**, the height of **AppBarLayout** has to be changed according to different **screen width** of the physical mobile device.

Therefore, I would like to know how should I dynamically define height of **AppBarLayout** and where should I define these ratio definition logic (I mean in which `callback` method of `Activity` java class).

[image: Keyline Matrics for AppBarLayout]

Comment: I was also facing same kind of issue. I would suggest that you can define height and width according to your screen size. Suppose in your current screen your upper portion cover 50% of screen and middle portion cover 20 % and the footer portion covers its 30% then you can create height and width for each and every screen and set that accordingly. Try this it may works for you.

Answer (score 4):

you can get a screen width and height using below code

`DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;`

calculate app bar layout height by using below formula

```
int appbar_height = width/1.5;
```

then set the Appbar height using

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,appbar_height);
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.appbar);
appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```